# Pseudocode for a searching tree

Tags: algorithms

I want to describe my search tree in an algorithm and describe how each level of the tree is created. But I cannot find good examples to help me express how to write it in an elegant way. Please if anyone can recommend a good resource for describing a search tree in detail in a pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to explain how such an algorithm works is via diagrams showing it step by step for some examples, examples selected to exercise your code more or less fully (need not cover all left/right symmetric cases, for example).

If you use LaTeX, look for a package to typeset algorithms, like `algorithm2e`, and check out Ti*k*Z and it's facilities to draw trees. It's documentation is quite forbidding, search for tutorials or targeted explanations.

Place yourself in the shoes of your gentle reader: What would you like to see? What points of the algorithm are thorny? Any corner cases that need explaining? Any strange/surprising/seemingly useless lines?